# mongodb sum of value monthly transaction

Tags: mongodb

I want to draw  graph based the monthly transaction details but i'm unable to get aggregate data from database. 
I have an item collection with following documents.

```
[{
 month:4,
 action:'credit',
 value:1000
 },
 {
 month:4,
 action:'credit'
 value:1000
 },
{
 month:5,
action:'debit'
 value:2000
 },
{
 month:4,
action:'debit'
 value:2000
 },{
 month:4,
action:'debit'
 value:500
 }

 {
 month:5,
action:'credit'
 value:2000
 }]
```

i want result like this

```
[ credit:{
month:[4,5]
data:[2000,2000]
}

Debit{
month[4,5]
data:[2500,2000]
}]
```

please any help me anyone

Comment: What have you tried? Happy to help you learn by providing pointers. Less happy to simply write your code for you when you have made no effort at all. Show that you have made a reasonable effort here and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: These should get you started. [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and if you have some familiarity with SQL then: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)